# What causes this Attribute Error encountered when implementing LangChain's OpenAI LLM wrapper?

Tags: python, dependencies, openai-api

This is my first post here. I'm building a Python window application with PyQt5 that implements interactions with the OpenAI completions endpoint. So far, any code that I've written myself has performed fine, and I was reaching the point where I wanted to start implementing long-term memory for conversational interactions. I started by just running my own chain of prompts for categorizing and writing topical subjects and summaries to text files, but I decided it best to try exploring open source options to see how the programming community is managing things. This led me to [LangChain](https://langchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which seems to have some popular support behind it and already implements many features that I intend.

However, I have not had even the tiniest bit of success with it yet. Even the most simple examples don't perform, regardless of what context I'm implementing it in (within a class, outside a class, in an asynchronous loop, to the console, to my text browsers within the main window, whatever) I always get the same error message.

The simplest possible example:

```
import os
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from local import constants #For API key
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.OPENAI_API_KEY
davinci = OpenAI(model_name= 'text-davinci-003', verbose=True, temperature=0.6)
text = "Write me a story about a guy who is frustrated with Python."
print("Prompt: " + text)
print(davinci(text))
```

It capably instantiates the wrapper and prints the prompt to the console, but at any point a command is sent through the wrapper's functions to receive generated text, it encounters this AttributeError.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\Pycharm Projects\workspace\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(davinci(text))
  File "D:\Dropbox\Pycharm Projects\workspace\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\base.py", line 255, in __call__
    return self.generate([prompt], stop=stop).generations[0][0].text
  File "D:\Dropbox\Pycharm Projects\workspace\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\base.py", line 128, in generate
    raise e
  File "D:\Dropbox\Pycharm Projects\workspace\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\base.py", line 125, in generate
    output = self._generate(prompts, stop=stop)
  File "D:\Dropbox\Pycharm Projects\workspace\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\openai.py", line 259, in _generate
    response = self.completion_with_retry(prompt=_prompts, **params)
  File "D:\Dropbox\Pycharm Projects\workspace\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\openai.py", line 200, in completion_with_retry
    retry_decorator = self._create_retry_decorator()
  File "D:\Dropbox\Pycharm Projects\workspace\venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\llms\openai.py", line 189, in _create_retry_decorator
    retry_if_exception_type(openai.error.Timeout)
AttributeError: module 'openai.error' has no attribute 'Timeout'
```

I don't expect that there is a fault in the LangChain library, because it seems like nobody else has experienced this problem. I imagine I may have some dependency issue? Or I do notice that others using the LangChain library are doing so in a notebook development environment, and my lack of familiarity in that regard is making me overlook some fundamental expectation of the library's use?
Any advice is welcome! Thanks!

What I tried: I initially just replaced my own function for managing calls to the completion endpoint with one that issued the calls through LangChain's llm wrapper. I expected it to work as easily as my own code had, but I received that error. I then stripped everything apart layer by layer attempting to instantiate the wrapper at every scope of the program, then I attempted to make the calls in an asynchronous function through a loop that waited to completion, and no matter what, I always get that same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be something about your current installed versions of Python, OpenAI, and/or LangChain. Maybe try using a newer version of Python and OpenAI. I'm new to Python and these things but hopefully I could help.

Comment: You were right. I had to set up a new environment with fresh installs of everything, and it's working now. I had feared that would be my only option and hoped to avoid it, but it will be easy enough to get everything up and running again. Cheers!